# profiling anonymous javascript functions (chrome)

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

when performance profiling in chrome anonymous high-use functions are difficult to trouble-shoot when they are listed at the root of the call tree.  is there a way to determine where an anonymous function was first instantiated?

Comment: You can go through and name all of your anonymous functions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably the easiest way is to put a `console.trace()` in your function.

Comment: Suppose you have no anonymous functions in your code - perhaps you are using library code which uses them.

Comment: Then the flamechart will show you where you are using these functions.

Answer (score 10):

You can utilize `console.profile([label])`, `console.profileEnd()`, `console.time([label])`, `console.timeEnd([label])`.

For example, execute the below in the JS snippet in console then review the `anonynous function` execution profile under '*Customize and control DevTools > More tools > JavaScript Profile*'.

```js
console.profile("anonymous function");
console.time("anonymous function");
(function() {
  var a = 123;
  function abc() {
    return a
  }
  abc();
}());
console.timeEnd("anonymous function");
console.profileEnd();
```

[image]

TIP: Storing JS in DevTools Snipets: Select `Sources` -> `Snippets` -> right-click -> select `New` -> place `javascript` within middle panel -> highlight / select text of `javascript` within middle panel -> right-click -> select `Evaluate in Console` -> click right-triangle at right panel or `Ctrl+Enter`.

Answer (score 4):

To find the origin of every call

1 - as [Yordan said](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36575732/3484498), you can use `console.trace`.

2 - You can also try :

```
console.log("called from : " + arguments.callee.caller.name.toString());
```

BUT this may be impossible in strict mode

```js
window.addEventListener("load", function() {
  var anon = function() {
    console.log("called from : " + arguments.callee.caller.name.toString());
  };
  
  function Test() {
    anon();
  }
  var anon2 = function() {
    anon();
  }
  
  Test(); // will display "Test"
  anon2(); // won't display a name (Anonymous caller)
});
```

If you need to profile a code block (in anonymous function or not) you can use `console.profile` / `console.profileEnd` and `console.time` / `console.timeEnd` (see [guest271314 answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36678418/3484498))

I recently made a little javascript plugin to help me debug time consumption in my apps : [MonitorJS](https://github.com/VincentCharpentier/MonitorJS) (1.35KB)

You can use it to measure how many CPU time a code block (function or not) is using over time.

e.g. :

```
// ...

function Test() {
  var mId = Monitor.Start("Foo");

  // Test function code
  // ...

  Monitor.Stop(mId);
}
```

Then you can check anytime in console :

```
Monitor.Get("Foo");
// return an object :
{
   name: "Foo",
   call_count: 32,
   // time in milliseconds, accurate to one thousandth of a millisecond
   total_time: 654.685
}
// you can calculate the average time per call
```

See the docs on [Github](https://github.com/VincentCharpentier/MonitorJS)

Hope this helps !