# Is there a way to find out any information about objects being released using chrome dev tools

Tags: javascript, performance, memory-management, google-chrome-devtools

I have the following code:

```
var constructors=[];
var counter = 0;

function start() {
    for (var i=100; i> 0; i--) {
        constructors.push(new arrayValues());
    }

    if (counter < 10) {
        setTimeout(function() {
            start();
        }, 1000);
    }

    counter++;
}

function arrayValues() {
    this.values = new Array(10000000).join("x");
}
```

Which creates dummy array and creates memory leaks. This pattern is clearly see on timeline. But I can also see that there's a release of objects (marked with red line). Is there a way to find any information about the objects being released, for example, when or where they where created, etc.?

[image]

**The question is not how to find the information by analyzing the code, but to find it using crhome-dev-tools**

Comment: I would assume `join` uses temporary memory which is deallocated by GC shortly afterwards. You are first creating and array and then converting it to a string after all, the previous' steps data is left for GC.

Comment: _"Is there a way to find any information about the objects being released, for example, when or where they where created, etc.?"_ Are you referencing the arrays being created?

Comment: @guest271314, they are reachable through `constructors` array

Comment: @ASDFGerte, thanks, but the question is not how to find that by analyzing the code, but to find it using crhome-dev-tools

Comment: @Maximus _"they are reachable through `constructors` array"_ Not certain what you mean? Are you trying to view function calls being made at `DevTools`?

Comment: @guest271314, I don't reference them in my code, that's correct. But I thought objects are removed only when there's no way to reach them, like `a.object = {}; a.object=null` - we can't reach `{}` anymore. But in my case I can still reference them if I want using `constructors[1].values`

Answer (score 1):

> The question is not how to find the information by analyzing the code,
>   but to find it using crhome-dev-tools

If interpret Question correctly, you can use [`console.profile()`](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/debug/console/console-reference?hl=en#profile), [`console.profileEnd()`](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/debug/console/console-reference?hl=en#profileend); `Record Heap Allocation`

See

[profiling anonymous javascript functions (chrome)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23962227/profiling-anonymous-javascript-functions-chrome/36678418#36678418)

[Are arrow functions optimized like named functions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36732782/are-fat-arrow-functions-optimized-like-named-functions/)

[How to detect the memory allocations that are triggering garbage collection in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39429647/how-to-detect-the-memory-allocations-that-are-triggering-garbage-collection-in-j/)

Comment: thanks, let me go through the resources you mentioned. can you recommend a book or articles to learn as much as possible about Chrome memory debugging capabilities

Comment: @Maximus See [Chrome DevTools](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/) , [Chrome DevTools Overview](https://developer.chrome.com/devtools)

Comment: thanks, if anything else comes to mind, please put it here