# How to find the catch statement for an error in the Chrome debugger?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, reactjs, google-chrome-devtools

I'm working with React. In a component constructor, an error is being thrown, but it's clearly being caught and swallowed because I only find out about it by clicking "Pause on Caught Exceptions." Is there any way to find out where the catch statement is? I've stepped through the code many times and have yet to find the catch statement.

Comment: See [profiling anonymous javascript functions (chrome)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23962227/profiling-anonymous-javascript-functions-chrome/)

Comment: the catch's error should be logged to console with the line number shown?...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you've paused on the caught exception, clicking "Step over" in the stepping controls should show you the catch handler.

[image]

Comment: This is probably right, I was just using a big awful library with utterly inscrutable error handling. I'm sure the catch was in there somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

For future reference, an alternative place an error might get 'caught' is [`Promise.allSettled`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/allSettled). The way I finally found this through a debugger was similar to Matt Zeunert's suggestion, but instead I did it in Firefox, which - unlike Google Chrome! - steps up through the stack trace in that case until it gets to the `Promise.allSettled`.